# how to get values of some values as type<String> which is inside a Map inside List in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: json, string, list, flutter, dart

I am trying to extract the values which key equal Name in a key:value pair that i extracted from an API. I am using the following formula;

```dart
final List<String> namesList =list.map((e) => e["Name"].toString()).toList();
print(namesList);
```

I can extract the values of name keys, however it is extracted as JSArray. I couldn't extract them as string.

Result: [Name1, Name2] JSArray
Should be: ["Name1", "Name2"] List

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Please refer to below code

```
void main() {
  List list = [
    {"code": "ABC", "Name": "\"Name1\"", "Type": "1"},
    {"code": "DEF", "Name": "\"Name2\"", "Type": "2"}
  ];

  final List<String> nameList = list.map((e) => e["Name"].toString()).toList();

  print(nameList);
  
  List list1 = [
    {"code": "ABC", "Name": "Name1", "Type": "1"},
    {"code": "DEF", "Name": "Name2", "Type": "2"}
  ];

  final List<String> nameList1 =
      list1.map((e) =>   '"${e["Name"].toString()}"').toList();
  print(nameList1);
}

// Result
// ["Name1", "Name2"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand the code but when i make "print(nameList1.runtype);" , it still shows JSArray<String>. Why it is shown JSArray but not List?  It is important because i am using searchfield package and this package only accepts List<String>.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that nameList element type is String.
The 'print' result only is shown remove double quotation marks.

[image]

Or you really want to make a list with double quotation marks.

```
void main() {
  List list = [{'Code': 'ABC', 'Name': 'Name1', 'Type': '1'}, {'Code': 'DEF', 'Name': 'Name1', 'Type': '2'}];
final List<String> namesList =list.map<String>((e) => "\"${e["Name"]}\"").toList();
print(namesList);
print(namesList[0].runtimeType);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand the code but when i make "print(namesList.runtype);" , it still shows JSArray<String>. Why it is shown JSArray but not List?  It is important because i am using searchfield package and this package only accepts List<String>.

Comment: I think that nameList is a 'List<String>' type. But dartpad print like that. When I test with dartpad flutter running not dart mode, runtimeType is 'List<String'.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seem there is no problem with the array. My problem is different i guess.